# Stitch css files and minify onthefly

Tags: php, css

I stitch css files to increase performance.

Now I want to include a minify function as below. How can I incorporate this?

```
function minify( $css ) {
    $css = preg_replace( '#\s+#', ' ', $css );
    $css = preg_replace( '#/\*.*?\*/#s', '', $css );
    $css = str_replace( '; ', ';', $css );
    $css = str_replace( ': ', ':', $css );
    $css = str_replace( ' {', '{', $css );
    $css = str_replace( '{ ', '{', $css );
    $css = str_replace( ', ', ',', $css );
    $css = str_replace( '} ', '}', $css );
    $css = str_replace( ';}', '}', $css );

    return trim( $css );
}
```

CODE FOR STITCHING:

```
<?php
$filename = $_GET['files']; 
// validate that $filename is set, contains only legal characters  
// and does not contain multiple dots (potential sign of trouble) 
if (!$filename || 
        !preg_match('/^([\.\-\_a-z0-9]*)$/i', $filename) || 
        preg_match('/([\.]{2,})/', $filename))     
    exit(); 

// we're sending CSS back to the browser 
header('Content-Type: text/css'); 

$files = explode('-', $filename, 15); 

// we're also writing CSS to a subdirectory "cache" 
// the filename will be the hyphen-delimited value  
// of $filename 
$cachefile = @fopen('cache/'. $filename, 'w'); 

// loop through, read each file, and stitch them together
foreach ($files AS $file) {
    $fcontents = null;     
    if ($cssfile = fopen($file, 'r')) {         
        $fcontents = fread($cssfile, filesize($file)) ."\n";         
        fclose($cssfile);     
    }

    // if we read something, write it and send it to browser     
    if ($fcontents) {
        fwrite($cachefile, $fcontents, strlen($fcontents));
        echo $fcontents;     
    }     
} 

// all done 
fclose($cachefile);
?>
```

Comment: By the way, you aren't correctly escaping the filename. Blacklisting dots is a bad idea, you should be checking that the real path you get is pointing to some place inside the cache directory. http://cwe.mitre.org/top25/#CWE-22

Comment: can you help me, 'cos I don't understand it.

Answer (score 6):

If you want, there's already a library that does this

http://code.google.com/p/cssmin/

usage:
`CSSMin::minify($css);`

Comment: Check this as an answer! Two thumbs up.

Comment: prefer my existing construction.

Comment: You are free to implement this yourself of course if you prefer, just make sure you get it right :)

Answer (score 0):

Do look at https://github.com/web-developer/Resource-Handler. This allows you to merege all your css into 1. It also does compress, minify and even cache your css. It also works for your js. This requires least configuration or hassle, unlike some of the other ones suggested .

RESOURCE HANDLER